# CKEditor5 imageUplaod - 'filerepository-no-upload-adapter'

Tags: angular, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am using CKEditor5.

I built it in Classic and ran it because there was an image upload icon in the toolbar.

However, as the title of the article states, an error occurred.

I have 'node_module/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-upload', but why doesn't it work?

Also, I want to load and use the file as base64 without saving it. Do I need a separate plugin?

I referred to the CKEditor5 Document and searched for many answers, but could not solve the problem.

`import Base64UploadAdapter from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5upload/src/adapters/base64uploadapter'; ClassicEditor.builtinPlugins = [ Base64UploadAdapter ]; ... export class { public Editor = ClassitEditor;`

'typeof Base64UploadAdapter' error

Comment: It would be great if you can provide some code for others to reproduce the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.